# Alt text not showing up

Tags: images

Morning all, 
I have read lots of messages on this subject but am no closer to getting alternative text for images working on my web pages. WP 4.9.2  running the Store99 theme. If I look in one of my posts I see the img text I read about.

It looks like this:

```
[caption id="attachment_5159" align="alignnone" width="150"]<img class="size-thumbnail wp-image-5159" src="https://cpapforbabyboomers.com/wp-content/uploads/Amara-View-Mask-mask-frame_with-Elbow_InPixio-150x150.jpg" alt="Amara_View" width="150" height="150" /> This is the Amara View Mask frame with elbow[/caption]
```

Is this not correct and if not what can I do to fix it?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do exactly, and every theme has its own quirks. Alternative Text and Caption are 2 different fields that do different things; if you want Alt text and you get Caption, make sure the text is entered in the right box when you edit the picture.

Comment: While i posted this questions there was text being written below the area I was typing and it shows the show entry,  above it not the complete entry, but I assure you I am putting the text in the right place.  Look at this capture.

Comment: We cannot see embedded images in comments. You should edit your question to include the screenshot, and all additional info such as what you are trying to accomplish exactly and what you have tried so far. You'll have much better chances of getting the answer you're looking for this way.

Comment: I did not realize you can not see that text.  You tell me I need to include a screenshot but I am unable to paste anything in here.  Can you tell me how to paste into this text area?  Sorry I am new to this forum but appreciate your help.

Comment: You can click Edit on your original question to get all the options and add images. However swissspidy's comment on his own answer has the info you need: What you‘re looking for is the title attribute. That's why it's important to explain what is your goal instead of just "It does not work".

Answer (score 1):

Your caption shortcode seems to be missing the most important part: the image.

The caption shortcode in WordPress usually looks like this:

```
[caption id="attachment_6" align="alignright" width="300"]<img src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/800px-Great_Wave_off_Kanagawa2-300x205.jpg" alt="Kanagawa" width="300" height="205" class="size-medium wp-image-6" /> The Great Wave[/caption]
```

There you can see the `alt` attribute, which is automatically set when you enter the alt text after uploading an image (here: "Kanagawa"). The alt text is not visible to users, but to programs like screen readers. The other text inside the shortcode ("The Great Wave") is the *caption*, which on the front end is displayed below the image.

If your theme does something completely different with the caption shortcode, you should contact the theme developer and ask them for help instead.

Comment: below is the complete text in the document.  Isn't the ALT+ in there and correct?  thanks 
<img class="wp-image-5159 size-thumbnail" src="https://cpapforbabyboomers.com/wp-content/uploads/Amara-View-Mask-mask-frame_with-Elbow_InPixio-150x150.jpg" alt="Amara_View" width="150" height="150" />

Comment: That looks like a valid image tag. In that case "Amara_View" is the alt text for that image.

Comment: I thought so also, but it does not work. Time to contact the theme manufacture ??  thanks,

Comment: Define „does not work“?

Comment: sorry @swisspidy.  the alt does not display when you mouse over the picture.   The caption does and yes I have tested it and removed the caption but still not alt text.

Comment: That‘s not how the alt text works. As I said: the alt text is NOT visible to users. What you‘re looking for is the title attribute. You can add it like this: `title="this will be shown on mouseover"`.

Comment: With that I completly do not understand then. The caption DOES show up when moused over so I guess all I can say is thanks and I will go learn about alt-txt.  thank you.